# How to determine most influenced parameters in dataset

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining

I have a dataset as a table with 15 columns. I would like to use cluster analisys for getting new knowledges. But I do not know which params use in analysis.

I understand, I should to determine parameters most affecting the data. Which of statistics methods I should apply to my data?

Please any examples, ideas, books, methods, procedures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start with [feature selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection).